# slow insert with RMySQL

Tags: r, rmysql

I have been using the package RMySQL

```
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
mydb <-  dbConnect(drv=drv,
                   user=*****,
                   password=******,
                   dbname=******,
                   host=*********, port = 3306)
```

I am doing insert to a raspberry PI

I am getting writing speeds very slow speeds, 10 seconds for 10000 records, possible reasons for that slow speed? My reading speeds are quite good.

Any suggestion on what to check?

Sincerely

Thank you very much

Comment: 10K records in 10 seconds doesn't even sound slow to me, especially if you have a lot of large columns.  For fastest inserts, look into using MySQL's `LOAD DATA` tool.

Comment: Did you make bulk insert or single row insert?

Comment: there are 8 columns and i do sendquery and I do send a string

Comment: is it better to do a bulk with dataframe? because the problem is the names of the columns isn't the same, although it is easy to modify and sput the same name to columns, will automatically identify it if I do like that?

Comment: could you share the `dbSendQuery` code you're using?

Comment: drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
mydb <-  dbConnect(drv=drv,
                   user=*****,
                   password=******,
                   dbname=******,
                   host=*********, port = 3306)


query<-"INSERT INTO tables_tbl(Param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,param6,param7,param8) VALUES(values1,values2,values3,values4,values5,values6,values7,values8);"


dbSendQuery(mydb, query)

Comment: Thank you fro your help

Comment: with the LOAD DATA tool can I pass the string directly using R?

Comment: load data would be using a file, sending this to the database and then exporting it to the table. It (might) already be part of `dbWriteTable`, depending on the driver implementation. You could read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) of the implementation for more information. :-)